# Definition of closed and open "Qanifolds" (manifolds over $\mathbb{Q}$): can a Qanifold be both closed and open?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds, rational-numbers

It is possible to define continuity over $\mathbb{Q},$ so it is possible to define a homeomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}.$ However, I don't see how we can define "closed" and "open" manifolds over $\mathbb{Q}$ (Qanifolds). My best definition is that a closed Qanifold is a Qanifold that can be extended to a closed manifold over $\mathbb{R},$ and an open Qanifold is a Qanifold that can be extended to an open manifold over $\mathbb{R}.$ Are there any Qanifolds that are both closed and open?

Comment: The problem with defining anything like this is that the homeomorphisms $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ are very strange. For example: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x^2<2\\-x&x^2>2\end{cases}$$ is a homeomorphism. The question needed before we can answer this is: What is the purpose of such a definition of Qanifold? What problems are you trying to solve? Generalizing just for the sake of generalizing can sometimes be useful, but I don't see any potential usefulness here. The completeness of $\mathbb R$ seems central to the usability for a concept like manifolds.

Comment: It seems a more natural generalization would be to use $p$-adic numbers. They are a complete metric space, but share the unfortunate topological property of the rationals that the space is not connected. Connectedness might be important.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q/Z}$ is an analytic Qanifold (the transition between charts are analytic).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $\Bbb Q\times \{ {\pi}\}\cup\{\pi\}\times \Bbb Q$ is somewhat surprisingly a 1dim Qanifold

Comment: What is a homeomorphism **over** ${\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: Same as the definition of a homeomorphism over R, but using "rational-continuity."

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "homeomorphism over ${\mathbb R}$." One can talk about homeomorphisms between subsets of ${\mathbb R}^n$ with respect to the subspace to topology, in particular, homeomorphisms between subsets of ${\mathbb Q}^n$. In algebraic geometry one talks about "morphisms over fields/rings", but this is something quite different.

Comment: All in all, you should really think about your terminology and adjust it to match the standard topological terminology. Here is another unclear example:  "can be extended to a closed manifold over ℝ". What is this supposed to mean ?(Yes, I know what "closed manifold" means classically, but what does it mean to "extend"?)  And you should clarify this not in comments but by editing your post.