# Is there a "rational-continuous" function that satisfies $f(f(x)) = 2x$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, rational-numbers

A function $f\colon\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ is rational-continuous at a rational number $\alpha$ iff for any $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists a corresponding $\delta$ based on $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon$ such that if $|\alpha-x| \leq \delta, |f(\alpha)-f(x)| \leq \varepsilon.$

It is easy to find a continuous function over the reals that satisfies $f(f(x)) = 2x.$ (Just take $f(x) = \sqrt{2}x.$) $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, so we can't use this on the rationals, and I believe that any function continuous over the reals that gives a rational number when evaluated on a rational number cannot satisfy $f(f(x)) = 2x$. However, [as](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604978/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1-on-rational-numbers-with-a-continuo) [we](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604684/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1-on-rational-numbers) [all](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604435/definition-of-closed-and-open-qanifolds-manifolds-over-mathbbq-can-a-q) [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605049/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1-on-rational-numbers-with-a-continuo), rational-continuity is weird. A rational-continuous function can "jump around," unlike continuous functions over the reals. Is there a rational-continuous function (jumpy or not) that satisfies $f(f(x)) = 2x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it which kind of side-steps the issue altogether.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      -x & x\leq 0 \\
      -2x & x>0 
\end{cases}
$$

The idea is just to use the fact composing $f$ twice lets you flip the real line around twice around the origin, and only multiply by $2$ on one of the halves.